# Fetching photos and tweets related to selected publications

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, pagination, active-record

- 1) Postgresql
- 2) User has_many :reports
- 3) Report belongs_to :user
- 3) Report belongs_to :publication
- 4) Publication has_many :reports
- 4) Publication scope :photos, -> `{ where(publication_type: 'Social::Photo').where(show: true) }`
- 4) Publication scope :tweets, -> `{ where(publication_type: 'Social::Tweet').where(show: true) }`

  ```
  def index

    looked_pub_ids = Publication.where(show: true).
      joins(:reports).
      where(reports: { user: current_user } ).
      pluck(:id)


    if looked_pub_ids.empty
      publicatons = Publication.all
    else
      publicatons = Publication.where( 'id NOT IN (?)', looked_pub_ids )
    end

    if request.xhr? && params[:id]
      @photos = publicatons.where('id > ?', params[:id]).
        photos.paginate(page: 1, per_page: 30)
      @tweets = publicatons.where('id > ?', params[:id]).
        tweets.paginate(page: 1, per_page: 30)
    else
      @photos = publicatons.photos.paginate(page: 1, per_page: 30)
      @tweets = publicatons.tweets.paginate(page: 1, per_page: 30)
    end
  end
  ```

Is there more optimal way to get photos, and tweets from Publication which the user has not reported (main target are admin-panel for manager, who will report some content)?

User see Publication, and can report them (Report table: user_id, publication_id) and next I do not have to show publications to user, what he had reported, example:

```
publication_1
publication_2
user_1
report_1: {user_id: 1, publication_id: 1}

user_1 can see only publication_2
```

Now I find all publication_id from `user.reports`, and then find all publication, except that ids, — I think it is not a nice solution.

P.S. Is it possible to write pure sql for getting that?